# Continuous Random Variables question

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

> The continuous random variable $X$ has p.d.f.  $$f(x) =\begin{cases}
>  \frac{2(7-x)}{25},&\text{for $2\leq x\leq 7$}\\ 0,& \text{otherwise}
>  \end{cases} $$
>
> The function $g(X)$ is defined by $g(x) = x^2 + x$
>
> Find the value of $E[g(X)]$.

Is the correct answer to this question $37/2$ or $397/6$? I disagree with the answer the textbook has given.

I believe the answer to be $37/2$, this is for 2 main reasons: Firstly, if you compute the integral of $(x^2 + x) (14/25 - 2x/25)$ with limits $2$ and $7$ then you get $37/2$. Secondly, an easier way. $E[X]$ in this case is $11/3$, and $E[X^2]$ is $89/6$ add them together: $89/6 + 11/3 = 37/2$. However, the textbook says the answer is $397/6$, and then follows up the question using this value.

Comment: Can you explain why do you disagree?

Comment: I believe the answer to be 37/2, this is for 2 main reasons:

Firstly, if you compute the integral of (x^2 + x) (14/25 - 2x/25) with limits 2 and 7 then you get 37/2

Secondly, an easier way. E(X) in this case is 11/3, and E(X^2) is 89/6 add them together: 89/6 + 11/3 = 37/2

This is why I think the answer is 37/2. However, the textbook says the answer is 397/6, and then follows up the question using this.

Comment: My calculation also yielded $18.5$. The textbook answer may be wrong.

Comment: Your definition of $f(x)$ uses $\gt$ not =. Why?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your calculations, which appear to be correct:

With probability $1$ we have that $2 < x \leq 7.$
Within the interval $2 < x \leq 7,$ 
the function $g(x) = x^2 + x$ has its maximum at $x = 7.$
With probability $1,$ therefore, $g(x) \leq g(7) = 56.$
This implies that $E[g(x)] \leq 56.$

Observing that $\frac{397}{6} > 66,$ we know that $E[g(x)]  \neq \frac{397}{6}.$